# how to use aync/await in angular 2 application using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, http-get

I developing angular 2 application, In that I implemented the functionality for getting the data from API.

This is the code I wrote in my service.ts.

```
  getTodoListApiUrl(): Observable<ISettings>{

    //return  this._http.get(this._UploadControllerUrl)
    //    .map((response: Response) => <Observable<ISettings[]>>response.json())
    //    .do(data =>console.log('todoListAPIUrl :' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    //    .catch(this.handleError);


    return this._http.get(this._UploadControllerUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <Observable<ISettings>>response.json())
        .do(data => this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl= data)
        .catch(this.handleError);     
}



getItems(): Observable<ITodoItem[]> {

    //alert(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl);
    if (this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl != null) {

        return this._http.get(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl + '/api/ToDoList').map((response: Response) => <ITodoItem[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All :' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    } else {

    }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log('App Component In OnInit');

    this._todoListService.getTodoListApiUrl()
        .subscribe(apiUrl => this.apiUrl = apiUrl,
        error => this.error = <any>error);

    //this._environmentTypeService.getTodoListApiUrl()
    //    .subscribe(apiUrl => this.apiUrl = apiUrl,
    //    error => this.error = <any>error);

    //this._environmentTypeService.getEnvironmentType()
    //    .subscribe(environmentType => this.environmentType = environmentType,
    //    error => this.error = <any>error);

}
```

In the above code i am storing the data of API result into some variable like this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl=data in getTodoListApirUrl() method.

But the compiler will not wait until the API gives result and store into above variable. it will automatically executes next method.

I think my above method can't wait until it gives result from api. can you please tell me how to make my above method should be like async/await.

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above issue.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Please use promise which is a subset of Observables

Sample code:-

**Service layer:-**

```
          getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
                return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
           }
```

**Controller layer:-**

```
         this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
```

Comment: In the above code toPromise() shows error, even I import the Observable.

Comment: please check the type of value returned by service  
                      AND
Check app/rxjs-operators.ts  file
It sholud have all imports------------------------

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Comment: in the above method where I am storing the result into my global variable like my observable method in my question. this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl=data